# how to get data from server when 1 condition is true in PHP android?

Tags: php, android, mysql

I am making PHP file where if the email is matched with email given in database, then it should show correct password.

I am new to PHP so don't know much about it.

Here is my php code:

```
<?php 

include ('config.php');

$sql = "SELECT * FROM UserInfo WHERE email='".$email."'";



$r = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

$result = array();

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($r)){

    array_push($result,array('password'=>$row['password'],));
}

echo json_encode(array('result'=>$result));

mysqli_close($con);

?>
```

I am getting this answer if I checked with browser {"result":[]}

Comment: Please please please learn about prepared statements. This, right here, is a SQL injection attack waiting to happen.

Comment: ok..will lear it ..but here plz tell me the correct answer

Comment: How do you set `$email`?

Comment: it will come from android app...i m a android develoepr

Comment: I mean to ask: how does it get set? I don't see any `$email = ...;` statement.

Comment: o yes tht i think i removed by mistake

Comment: $email = $_POST['email'];

Comment: can u tell me if the email which i send from server matches the email of datatabse then how can we fetch password

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132279/discussion-between-z-al-and-daan-meijer).

Answer (score 0):

use below code you will get all result

```
$m = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM `UserInfo` WHERE `email`='".$email."'");
         while($result=mysqli_fetch_assoc($m))
            {
             $flag[]=$result;
            } 
         print(json_encode($flag));
```

Comment: getting null value

Comment: $email =put email which is present in database

Answer (score 0):

**step 1 connection with database make new db_connect.php file**

**do needful changes change** `'Host','USER','PASS','DB'`

```
<?php
 define('HOST','localhost');
 define('USER','root');
 define('PASS','Root@123');
 define('DB','your database name');

 $con = mysqli_connect(HOST,USER,PASS,DB) or die('Unable to Connect');
 ?>
```

check connection using below URL do needful changes

```
http://192.168.1.85/AskUsCash/db_connect.php

http://ip address/folder name/db_connect.php
```

**Make php file  test.php**

check table name and column name are same as in query if not then change it from php file. make sure your table name is `UserInfo` and column name is `email`

```
<?php
    include 'db_connect.php';
    $request=$_REQUEST['getdata'];

     // customer Registration form
    if($request=="checkEmail")
        {
             $Email =$_REQUEST['insert_Email'];  
             $m = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM `UserInfo` WHERE `email`='".$Email."'");
             while($result=mysqli_fetch_assoc($m))
                {
                 $flag[]=$result;
                } 
             print(json_encode($flag));

        }
    else
    {

        $flag['Error']='2';
        print(json_encode($flag));      

    }       
    ?>
```

**check result  do needful changes below is my url**

```
   http://192.168.1.85/AskUsCash/db_connect.php
192.168.1.85/AskUsCash/test.php/?getdata=checkEmail&insert_Email=borhadyog@gmail.com
```

change with your credential.

http://192.168.1.85/AskUsCash/db_connect.php

and pass parameter from

```
?getdata=checkEmail&insert_Email=borhadyog@gmail.com
```

valid email which is in database change email address